# How to properly update subtotal in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a JavaScript update total function that I can't seem to figure out. It seems to be firing twice when a drop down gets updated, and by doing so it's adding an extra cost that shouldn't be there.

Here's my present code:

```
var updateTotal = function(option) {
  var sumtotal;
  var sum = 0;

  // Add each product price to total
  $(".product").each(function() {
    var price = $(this).data('price');
    var selector = document.getElementById('variety_weight');
    var quantity = selector[selector.selectedIndex].value;
    var ptotal = $(packaging).find('option:selected').val();

    if (ptotal == 2) {
      var burlap = 4.99;
      var subburlap = quantity * burlap;
      var subtotal = price * quantity + subburlap;
    } else {
      var subburlap = 0.00;
      var subtotal = price * quantity;
    }

    // Round to 2 decimal places.
    subtotal = subtotal.toFixed(2);

    // Display subtotal in HTML element
    $('.productTotal', this).html(subtotal);
  });

  // Total
  $('.productTotal').each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).html());
  });

  sum = sum + 9.99;
  $('#sum').html(sum.toFixed(2));
};
```

And my initial code is this:

```
$('#variety_weight').change(function() {
  /*
   * Setting currently changed option value to option variable.
   */
  var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();

  /*
   * Setting input box value to selected option value.
   */
  alert("Firing variety");
  updateTotal();
});

$('#packaging').change(function() {
  /*
   * Setting currently changed option value to option variable.
   */
  var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
  alert(option);

  /*
   * Setting input box value to selected option value.
   */
  alert("Firing packaging");
  updateTotal(option);
});

// Set this from local
$('span.productTotal').each(function() {
  $(this).before("")
});

// Unit price
$('.product p').each(function() {
  var $price = $(this).parents("div").data('price');
  $(this).before($price);
});

// Update totals when page first loads
updateTotal();
```

The end result is that when a user selects the packaging option and switches it to option 2 - I'm trying to make it so that it will take the quantity and times it by 4.99 per and then add it to the sub total.

But my issue is - that while the initial load and `updateTotal()` function works fine - it's only when the packaging option is selected that it appears to be calling the `updateTotal()` function twice as it will add 9.98 instead of just 4.99.

Comment: could you post the html as well ?

Comment: Do you have more than one element with id packaging?

Comment: Why are you assigning variable inside the scope of if-else conditionals? You should declare them outside of the conditional if you intend to use them afterwards. It may work in JavaScript, but it is not the correct and accepted way.

Comment: Are you expecting selector, quantity or ptotal to vary per product?

Comment: @JonSG selector essentially becomes quantity so it's just quantity and ptotal

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl while your answer didn't provide the code (which I'm ok with) it did however set me on the right path to do a little rewrite to fix it. It's working properly now. Thanks for the input and insight!

Comment: But selector is not specific to a product as it is based on an element with a specific id, right?  So neither is quantity nor ptotal as it is based on a different static element id.  The only variable that seems to be sensitive to product is price.  If that is what you want that is cool.  Alternatively, how is quantity varying per product?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to figure out without knowing what data the view elements (used in logic) contain. However, my suggestion is

This is one of the common side effects of having view and business logic tied together, in other words not having clear separation of concerns. All MV* frameworks like AngularJS, Backbone, Ember are addressing it.

At least, try to perform business logic (calculation, foreach, etc) on JavaScript objects then set results to view elements finally which is more clean, reliable and easy to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

You say that it should add only 4.99, but you do this when the option 2 is selected

`var subburlap = quantity * burlap;
 var subtotal = price * quantity + subburlap;`

What is quantity value there? Well

```
var quantity = selector[selector.selectedIndex].value;
```

Quantity equals 2. So you dont seem to be firing the event twice, rather adding your packaging value wrongly.